# Cannot get app name correctly in android API 30 or higher

Tags: android

I want to get a list of app names installed on android phone.
However, when I run my code, I can't get some of the app names correctly as shown below.

```
D/applicationName: com.android.gallery3d.app.GalleryActivity
D/applicationName: Messaging
D/applicationName: Settings
D/applicationName: Maps
D/applicationName: com.android.documentsui.LauncherActivity
D/applicationName: res/menu/example_menu.xml
D/applicationName: res/color/abc_primary_text_material_light.xml
```

Also, when the correct app name cannot be obtained, the following error occurs

```
E/mple.getapplis: Resource 7f100082 is a complex map type.
W/PackageManager: Failure retrieving text 0x7f100082 in package com.android.documentsui
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f100082
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:444)
        at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getText(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2004)
        at android.content.pm.ComponentInfo.loadUnsafeLabel(ComponentInfo.java:103)
        at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadLabel(PackageItemInfo.java:210)
        at android.content.pm.ResolveInfo.loadLabel(ResolveInfo.java:225)
        at com.example.getapplist.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:22)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7994)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7978)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Sometimes I get a list of each app name is correct, but after a few builds, the above situation occurs.
And this situation occurs only if my code runs in api 30 and above.
My code is below.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val pm = this.packageManager
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.action = Intent.ACTION_MAIN
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
        val applications = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0)
        for (resolverInfo in applications) {
            val applicationName = resolverInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString()
            Log.d("applicationName", applicationName)
        }

    }
}
```

I already added following setting in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"
    tools:ignore="QueryAllPackagesPermission" />
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed my app and rebuilt, this problem was solved! I think this is a bug of IDE.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public String getAppLable(Context context) {
PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = null;
try {
    applicationInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(context.getApplicationInfo().packageName, 0);
} catch (final NameNotFoundException e) {
}
return (String) (applicationInfo != null ? packageManager.getApplicationLabel(applicationInfo) : "Unknown");
```

}

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However, this code only returns the name of its own app, the other apps' name installed on the android can't get.